# Array PHP, if array changes

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a way to execute a code only when my array has a new value passed on in position [0];?

```
if(?){

print_r(array_values($parcels)[0]);

} else{}
```

tried multiple statements but all lead to error or invalid. If a new order comes in `array[0]` gets replaced with that info. So only when that info has changed execute this.. Is this Possible?

Comment: No. Arrays are too simple a structure. You'd need something like a wrapper class

Comment: What do you mean? A new value at pos 0 or just that there must be a value in position 0?

Comment: @micheal , yes the first 1. the value changes at position 0 when the order gets in. The value of array[0] gets put 1 aside to array[1] and array[0] is updated with the new information. Sorry for the not clear example. Still need to learn to write my question correctly. and kingkero thank you ! i will look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the old value in an other variable to compare it. So you are able to consider if the value has changed.

```
$oldValue = $parcels[0];

//-------
//Code that eventually changes the array
//-------

if($oldValue != $parcels[0]) {
    print_r(array_values($parcels)[0]);
    $oldValue = $parcels[0];
} else{}
```